# show that for any natural number k, $R(T^{k+1})$ is a subspace/subset of $R(T^k)$, and that $N(T^k)$ is a subspace/subset of $N(T^{k+1})$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

so I was wondering if you can help me out with the following:

Let $T: V \rightarrow V$ , $V$ is a vector space and $T$ is linear

Show that for any natural number k, $R(T^{k+1})$ is a subspace/subset of $R(T^k)$, and that $N(T^k)$ is a subspace/subset of $N(T^{k+1})$.

So naturally I wanted to try mathematical induction, but my Professor claim that there is a one-line proof that involves only the definition of Range and Null-space.

Intuitively, I can see why  $R(T^{k+1})$ is a subspace/subset of $R(T^k)$, because we are applying T to $R(T^k)$ which is a subspace of V, thus we have "lesser" elements for T to apply to. But I don't know how to see intuitively that $N(T^k)$ is a subspace/subset of $N(T^{k+1})$ without using the rank-nullity theorem.

Hence I'm hoping I can get some answers on what exactly is the one line proof my Professor is talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $v\in R(T^{k+1})$, say $v=T^{k+1}w$. Then $v=T^k(Tw)$, so $v\in R(T^k)$.

Suppose $v\in N(T^k)$, i.e., $T^kv=0$. Then $T^{k+1}v=T(T^kv)=T(0)=0$, i.e., $v\in N(T^{k+1})$.